# Troubles with shell script versus terminal on Pi

Tags: windows, shell, terminal, shared, raspberry-pi

I am trying to share a folder on a windows computer with the raspberry pi.

when I use these commands in terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/foldername
sudo mount -t cifs //IPADDRESS/folderIwanttoaccess/ -o username=usrname,password=passwrd /mnt/foldername
```

This works fine and I am able to save files on the raspberry pi to the windows shared folder.

but when I try this in a shell script I am able to see the folder as shared but with "^m" at the end.

for example: Foldername^M

Why does this happen and is there a way around to stop the "^m"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2009/04/09/dos2unix-using-sed-how-to-remove-m-chars-from-a-dos-file/), you can sort your problem using [sed](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sed++NetBSD-current), merely by using the following incantation: `s/^M$//`. Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks the file was written on a windows computer and needed the LF not CR to get the shell to work.

Thanks a lot for your help!